# Three.js/A-Frame cubecamera black and no texture on objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I've added a cubecamera to my A-Frame Scene via Three.js (v.0.8.0) Code and when I want to project the captured cubecamera texture as envMap to e.g. a sphere, this is the result: [cubecamera texture on sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6lbz.png)

It basically doesn't show the textures of the surrounding objects and some objects are plain black. I tried for hours now and Iam exhausted. Some tips and/or solutions? Thanks!

My cubecamera code:

```
function setupCubecam(){
    var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 0.005, 100000, 64 );
    scene.add( cubeCamera );

    var cubecamMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture,
        metalness: 1,
        roughness: 0,
    });

    sphere.material = cubecamMaterial;
    sphere.visible = false;

    cubeCamera.position.copy( sphere.position );
    cubeCamera.update( renderer, scene );

    sphere.visible = true;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

**EDIT :**
And I get this error when assigning the cubeCamera as envMap to the Material:

```
Error: WebGL warning: texParameteri: pname 0x2802: Invalid param 0x0000. three.js:18014:4
Error: WebGL warning: texParameteri: pname 0x2803: Invalid param 0x0000. three.js:18015:4
Error: WebGL warning: texParameteri: pname 0x2802: Invalid param 0x0000. three.js:18014:4
Error: WebGL warning: texParameteri: pname 0x2803: Invalid param 0x0000. three.js:18015:4
```

**EDIT 2:** When I remove the materials from the other objects, it works. [without other materials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66epX.png)
These are the other Materials:

```
var wall_MAT = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: wallTexture,
    aoMap: wallAO,
    metalness: 0,
    lights: true,
});

var floor_MAT = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: floorTexture,
    aoMap: floorAO,
    metalnessMap: floorMETAL,
    envMap: floorENV,
    metalness: 1,
    roughness: 0,
    lights: true,
});
```

**EDIT 3:** So I figured out that the texture is my problem. It works with plain colors. (But why?) [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8DSl.png)

Comment: Do you have better results when using a different material like `MeshPhongMaterial`? Besides, is it possible for you to demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)?

Comment: @Mugen87 Thank you for your fast answer. I tried all kind of materials and it's the same. I am afraid that i can't upload this direct example on jsfiddle because of legal restrictions :/ I would have to build a simliar scene to show it. Give me some minutes to recreate.

Comment: @Mugen87 I also get four errors in the console. I edited my post.

Comment: Have you tried setting color: 0xffffff ?